# Adding line breaks to text output file

Tags: python

IDE output shows line breaks but txt output file does not. What am i missing?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

source = requests.get('https://dota2.gamepedia.com/Category:Counters').text

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
link = soup.find('div', class_="mw-category")

heroes_names = []

savefile = open('file.txt', 'w')

for link in link:
    link = link.text
    heroes = link.split("\n"
    for i in range(1,len(heroes)):
        heroname = heroes[i].split("/")[0]
        print(heroname)
        heroes_names.append(heroname)
        savefile.write(heroname)

# for hero_name in heroes_names:
#     print(hero_name)


savefile.close()
```

**required output to txt file (without the bullets) :**

- Abaddon
- Alchemist
- Ancient Apparition
- Anti-Mage
- Arc Warden
- Axe
- Bane

**actual output to txt file :**
AbaddonAlchemistAncient ApparitionAnti-MageArc WardenAxeBane

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
savefile.write(heroname)
```

do

```
savefile.writeline(heroname + "\n")
```

which will add a linefeed character to the end of your output.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, dont write in file each time in loop. Do it in your below code commented
Also dont open file like you do

```
with open("file.txt", "a+") as f:
    for hero_name in heroes_names:
        print("Will write: %s" %hero_name)
        f.write("%s\n" %hero_name)
```